# Loading File works in compiled exe but not when run inside visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, file-io

I am trying to load an image into my program using stb_image. Every time i run the program directly inside of visual studio (pressing f5, happens in debug and release) the opening of the File fails. If i run the compiled exe in windows explorer the loading works just fine. The same problem occured when using fstream to load a textfile into a string.

I tried placing the files in the directory of my code and into the final build folder but with no different outcome. Running Visual Studio with different Rights and different build settings.

Comment: My advice is to use your debugger to see why. Put a breakpoint in your code where it opens your file and see  what happens when you step through the code that opens the file. Also your code should have some form of error handling.

Comment: What's the error? When you know what error is being returned you'll know what the problem is.

Comment: Are you loading the file using a **relative** or **absolute** file path? If relative, it could certainly fail, since the starting working directory of the process is likely not what you are expecting when run within the IDE. ALWAYS use absolute paths at runtime, if you are not already doing so.

Comment: So stb_image use fopen_s as function for loading the file. It is returning a ernno_t with the value 2. This means no such File or Directory. But the file is present, and it can be opend  if i run the compiled exe outside of VS. The Problem only occures when i am trying to run the programm inside of Visual Studio.

Comment: ***This means no such File or Directory. But the file is present,*** Look at the path to the image file in your debugger when you debug. Perhaps the path was corrupted for some reason.

Comment: Using absolute paths with double backslashes fixed it. I feel like a moron now. How can i set a comment as an answer?

Comment: You can answer your own question if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Using absolute paths in the loading function fixed the problem.